# Google App Engine SDK for Python

Tags: python, sdk

Прохожу туториал в [документации по Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading), и не могу понять, куда в восьмом задании по созданию Гостевой книги вызывать команду `appcfg.py -A <YOUR_PROJECT_ID_> update guestbook/`

Answer (score 1):

Вызывать в cmd, по директории в папке с проектом.